# Handle a Keyerror when the data does not exist in an api

Tags: python

I have this loop that goes through a dictionary obtained from an api, however when arriving at a key that does not exist, it shows me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C: \ git_work \ reports_rhev \ reports_rhev \ Reporte_RHV_vM_v1.0.py", line 25, in <module>
     version = data.get (element ['guest_operating_system'] ['version'] ['full_version'])
KeyError: 'guest_operating_system'
```

In this case how could I handle the keyerror, how could I apply the get method in this case?

```
URL = https://api/ovirt-engine/api/vms
data = requests.get(URL, verify=False, auth = HTTPBasicAuth('admin@internal','password'), headers={'Accept': 'application/json'}) #Configuración de URL
data = data.json() #Convertimos la respuesta a un diccionario de datos

#print(type(data))

## Recorrer con todos los elemento dentro del diccionario de datos y obtener la información de las vMS

for elemento in data['vm']: #Recorrer el elemento host dentro de la variable data
    
    name_vm = elemento['name']
    descripcion = elemento['description']
    version = elemento['guest_operating_system']['version']['full_version']

    print(f"vM: {name_vm}\nDescripción: {descripcion}")
```

Try to do this but it doesn't work:

```
for elemento in data['vm']: #Recorrer el elemento host dentro de la variable data

name_vm = elemento['name']
descripcion = elemento['description']

if elemento['guest_operating_system'] in data['vm']:
    version = elemento['guest_operating_system']['version']['full_version'] 
else:
    version = "Dato no disponible"

print(f"vM: {name_vm}\nDescripción: {descripcion}\nVersión: {version}")
```

Comment: well, its actually clear that there's no key named as `'guest_operating_system'` in the dictionary, so you can just do something like this `version = elemento['guest_operating_system']['version']['full_version'] if elemento['guest_operating_system']`

Comment: @GhostOps - two problems with that. 1) the if will raise the keyerror, and 2) you need an else.

Comment: What do you want to do when the key isn't there? You can do `if 'guest_operating_system' in elemoto:` to test whether that key is in the dictionary and base your actions from there. I'm not sure what you'd like that action to be. You could also just keep doing what you are doing and let the `KeyError` mean that the whole operation should fail.

Comment: what do you mean the if will fail? `version = elemento['guest_operating_system']['version']['full_version'] if elemento['guest_operating_system'] else 'Data not available'` this will definitely work one line if statement

Comment: @GhostOps - The error says that 'guest_operating_system' is not in the collection. The `if elemento['guest_operating_system']` will raise a KeyError before the `if` part even runs. You won't get so far as the else.

Comment: When the if fails, data not available appears

Comment: dict.get("your_expected_key", <a default value, for instance None>) and then check the output.

Comment: Thank you all for your knowledge and time, you can now solve it, how can I upload the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following

- `'key' in dict`
- `.get('key', default)`, or exclude the default argument to return `None` without an Error

You cannot call `.get()` on None, though, or a non-dict result, so best not to chain them

Example of each

```
for elemento in data.get('vm', []): 
    
    name_vm = elemento['name']
    description = elemento['description']
    os = elemento.get('guest_operating_system')
    if (os is not None) and ('version' in os) and ('full_version' in os['version']):
        version = os['version']['full_version']
    else:
        version = None

    print(f"vM: {name_vm}\nDescripción: {descripcion}\nVersion: {version}")
```

Comment: You can chain them if you pass an empty dict as default, such as `elemento.get('x', {}).get('y', {}).get('z')`

Comment: True, but for the example given, I don't think guessing a default value for `full_version` is reasonable

Comment: It's not guessing a default value, rather is ensuring that if a nested value exists, you'll be able to get it. If it doesn't, it won't raise errors. I think it's important to note this only because from the answer it gives (to me at least) the impression that it's not possible to chain `get` calls in dicts to avoid key errors.

Comment: Some other thoughts: since `os` is obtained through an `get` without default, the conditional could use `is not None`, which is the conventional way of comparing to `None`, as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id49). If `os` returns any 'falsy' value, the current solution will not be prepared.